# Using KerasRegressor with cross_validate fails because of uncloneability

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I am using Keras' sklearn wrapper for a regressor, namely [`tf.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasRegressor).
I want this regressor to work within sklearn's cross validation scheme, namely [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html).

The regressor generally works without CV.
However, the latter fails, because I have a necessary parameter in the regressor's `__init__` method that defines the batch input shape and it appears to be missing.
This seems to be the case because `MyRegressor` or `KerasRegressor` isn't correctly cloneable using [`clone(estimator)`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L269). The specific error message is:

```
KeyError: 'batch_input_shape'
```

Is there a way to make `MyRegressor` work with `cross_validate`? Am I somehow violating sklearn's requirements?

Please see this condensed working example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor

class MyRegressor(KerasRegressor):
    def __init__(self, batch_input_shape, build_fn=None, **kwargs):
        self.batch_input_shape = batch_input_shape
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *kwargs):
        model = Sequential([
            LSTM(16, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=self.batch_input_shape),
            Dense(1),
        ])
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['RootMeanSquaredError'])
        return model

    def reset_states(self):
        self.model.reset_states()

X, y = make_regression(6400, 5)
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
batch_size = 64
batch_input_shape = (batch_size, 1, X.shape[-1])

# Works fine
reg = MyRegressor(batch_input_shape)
for i in range(10):
    reg.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size)
    reg.reset_states()

# Doesn't work
reg = MyRegressor(batch_input_shape)
results = cross_validate(reg, X, y, scoring=['neg_mean_squared_error'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloneability requires a proper `get_params` method.  Most often this is obtained by inheriting from sklearn's `BaseEstimator`, but `KerasRegressor` instead implements its own directly ([source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3a33d53ea4aca312c5ad650b4883d9bac608a32e/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L104)).  The way it does it is incompatible with your additional `batch_input_shape`; you can tweak it to make things work:

```
    def get_params(self, deep=False):
        res = self.sk_params.copy()  # sk_params was set by KerasRegressor.__init__
        res.update({
            'build_fn': self.build_fn,
            'batch_input_shape': self.batch_input_shape,
        })
        return res
```

(I get an error in your example after this update, about input shapes.  But I'm less familiar with batch sizes and keras to be able to answer that followup.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This indeed solves the initial error message. The later resulting problem comes from `cross_validate` calling `reg.fit` without defining `batch_input_shape`. I don't know if this is really possible, since I think sklearn to assume only `X` and `y` for the `fit` method.

Comment: @Felix, `cross_validate` takes a `fit_params` dictionary.  (But that didn't resolve the error for me.)

Comment: thanks for the hint. You are correct that this didn't – but actually should – resolve this. This is because the [`BaseWrapper`'s `fit` method is limited](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L164) to a set of parameters that is not representative of `KerasRegressor`. What's more to be found in the source code: "DEPRECATED. Use [Sci-Keras](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras) instead."